# Ошибка при добавление имени классу : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined js

Tags: javascript, html

*Что бы было понятнее моя проблема, я напишу сначала 1 вариант кода а потом второй. (Java Script)*
1 Код:

```js
var img      = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__li"); //Массив классов с картинками (не активные)
var btn      = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__btn"); //Массив классов с кнопками (не активные)
var page     = document.querySelectorAll(".slider_page_li"); //Массив 2 кнопок
var index    = 0; 
var interval = null;

function moveInterval(){ //Переход картинок и кнопок
    prevClass(img, index, "slider__li"); //Начальная картинка
    prevClass(page, index, "slider_page_li"); //Начальная кнопка
    index++; //Увеличиваем index каждый раз вызывая эту функцию
    if(index >= img.length){
        index = 0;
    }
    nextClass(img, index, "slider__li slider__li_active"); //Меняем картинку под индексом на активную.
    nextClass(page, index, "slider_page_li slider_page_li_active"); //Меняем кнопку под индексом на активную.
}

function prevClass(obj, index, strClass){ //Передаем obj, индекс, и strClass.
    obj[index].className = strClass; 
}
function nextClass(obj, index, strClass){ //Функция для изменение название класса передаваемого элемента под индексом
    obj[index].className = strClass;
}

function startSlide(time){ //Функция по моему для старта 'moveInterval' по заданому времени
    interval = setInterval(moveInterval , time);
}

startSlide(2000); //Вызываем 'startSlide' и каждый 2 секунды вызывается 'moveInterval'
```

Java Script недавно начал изучать.

**Как вы поняли, я вызываю функцию каждый 2 секунды, которая в свою очередь увеличивает index и меняет название класса элемента.**

2 Код:

```js
var img      = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__li");
var btn      = document.querySelectorAll(".slider__btn");
var page     = document.querySelectorAll(".slider_page_li");
var index    = 0;
var interval = null;

function target(){ 
    prevClass(img, index, "slider__li"); //Начальные значения элемента img.
    prevClass(page, index, "slider_page_li"); //Начальные значения элемента page.
    if(this.dataset.target === "next"){ //Если элемент имеет data_target="next то:
        index++; //Увеличивает index
        if(index >= img.length){ // проверяет больше или равно максимальному числу картинок
            index = 0; // Если так то обнуляет index
        }
    }else if(this.dataset.target === "prev"){ ////Если элемент имеет data_target="prev" то:
        index--; //Убавляет index
        if(index = 0){ //Если index = 0
            index = img.length - 1; //По моему по этой строки мы делаем начальный index
        }
    }else{ 
        index = parseInt(this.dataset.target);
    }
    nextClass(img, index, "slider__li slider__li_active"); //ТУТ ВОЗНИКАЕТ ОШИБКА
    nextClass(page, index, "slider_page_li slider_page_li_active"); //ТУТ ВОЗНИКАЕТ ОШИБКА
}

function prevClass(obj, index, strClass){
    obj[index].className = strClass; //ТУТ ВОЗНИКАЕТ ОШИБКА: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined
}
function nextClass(obj, index, strClass){
    obj[index].className = strClass; //ТУТ ВОЗНИКАЕТ ОШИБКА: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined
}

Array.prototype.map.call(page, function(e){ //Вызов функции target при клики на page
    e.addEventListener("click", target);
});
Array.prototype.map.call(btn, function(e){//Вызов функции target при клики на btn
    e.addEventListener("click", target);
});
```

В общем то в 2 коде возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined
(Если что я подметил где именно в комментариях).

И как я понял, что ли не существует... Я вообще не понимаю! Прошу помощи! Если нужно что то дополнить то напишите!

Comment: > //Массив **2** кнопок Почему Вы используете тот же индекс что и для `img`, если кнопок только две?

Comment: Добавьте вывод в консоль что такое `obj`, `index`. Очевидно, проблема в том что obj[index] не существует, и значит либо у вас нет элементов с подходящим классом и `img` хранит пустой массив, либо вы устанавливаете неверный индекс.

Comment: Вывел.
Скрин вывода: http://prnt.sc/114xgay
Но что то у меня не выводиться index. Именно в блоке if/else

Answer (score 1):

Извините что так вышло! Все понял.
Даже странно то что начал создавать вопрос.

В общем то, я просто в элементе написал не 'data-target' а 'data_target'.